# manipulating routes in different lerna monorepos

Tags: reactjs, react-router, lerna, monorepo

I have a lerna monorepo which I use in it web components for my packages:

```
| packages/
| -- app
| ---- index.ts
| ---- package.json
| -- project-2
| ---- index.ts
| ---- package.json
| -- project-3
| ---- index.ts
| ---- package.json
| package.json
```

where:

```
| -- app
    | ---- index.ts  ==> <Switch>
                          <Route exact path="/link" render={() => (<web-component-1 /> )} />
                         <Route exact path="/" render={() => <web-component-2 />} />
                        </Switch>
```

and in `web-component-2` I have the following routes to render them:

```
| -- project-2
    | ---- index.ts ==> <Switch>
                          <Route exact path="/link" render={() => (<component1 /> )} />
                          <Route exact path="/link2" render={() => (<component2 /> )} />
                          <Route exact path="/link3" render={() => (<component3 /> )} />
                          <Route exact path="/" render={() => <home />} />
                        </Switch>
```

so, my project once it render to home page, and in order to display `home` component, I have to reload the page twice to make it recognize it which is not logical. How can I prevent this?